# Searching for a word in multiple files

Tags: linux, bash

My code looks for a word in two log files but the way I did not seem efficient.
Anyone know a better way?

```
     for IP in `grep "$TERM" ${IPECONFIG[APACHELOGFILE]} | grep "$TERM" ${IPECONFIG[APACHESSLLOGFILE]} | awk "{print \\$1}" | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -40 | awk "{if (\\$1 > ${IPECONFIG[THRESHOLD]}) print \\$2}"`
     do

     # do something

done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grep accepts multiple filenames on the command line. Your shell parameter expansion would actually be doing this. If you run `ls -l ${IPECONFIG[APACHELOGFILE]}` you will see how many files show up with that search.

You can combine your grep operations as such:

```
grep "$TERM" ${IPECONFIG[APACHELOGFILE]} ${IPECONFIG[APACHESSLLOGFILE]}"
```

Comment: I will try this `grep -h "admin" /var/log/apache2/access.log /var/log/apache2/ssl_access.log`